# Read text file from relative path within project

Tags: c#, .net

I am creating a unit test which works using the following exact path:

`string path = @"/Users/{username}/Coding/computershare/ChallengeSampleDataSet1.txt";`

I read the text from the file by passing this path

`string pricesFromFile = System.IO.File.ReadAllText(path);`

However, I do not want to hardcode the complete local file path - I want to use the relative path in the project directory.

Therefore I tried the below using other articles on StackOverflow:

`string path =  System.IO.Path.Combine(System.AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory, "ChallengeSampleDataSet1.txt");`

But file is not found. How can I fix this so that I'm able to load the file when running the app from another machine?

Edit: the error in console using the second method is

`System.IO.FileNotFoundException : Could not find file '/Users/{username}/Coding/computershare/bin/Debug/net5.0/ChallengeSampleDataSet1.txt'.`

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should do the trick:

`string path =  System.IO.Path.Combine(System.AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory + @"..\..\..\", "ChallengeSampleDataSet1.txt");`

**Note the direction of the slash (\)**

Since the error is "/Users/{username}/Coding/computershare/bin/Debug/net5.0/ChallengeSampleDataSet1.txt" it indicates that your base directory is /bin/debug/net5.0 down from the root of the code.  By double dotting up three levels, you'll be able to find the file in question.

Comment: This works but i had to invert the \ to / because i'm in a unix environment (I think). When I did that, it worked anyway. Thank you.

Comment: I'll accept your answer but please edit/highlight the / direction in an edit for future users if you don't mind

Comment: @loco Agreed and Done!